# Can I use deep linking in flutter as a trigger?

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I am deep linking into my app, or at least trying to. Let's make a fictional example:

```
// my clock app
myapp://timer?102seconds
```

If I understand deep links correctly, they kind of work like URLs on websites. Go to the page described in the link. This I don't need and honestly I don't think it would work even. I have a few screens on the App which I want to be able to be called like a Trigger.

In the example above I want the app to receive `timer?102seconds`, so that my app itself can

-be opened with the uri

- is it a timer or a stopwatch or an alarm
- if it is a timer, how long should it be
- push the timer page on the navigator
- give the bloc the info of time that I need here

I am not sure how possible that is, but it is the easiest way I can imagine implementing this here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/receive) you can encode another link, from which you can extract data. Check out [this link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/Uri-class.html) to see documentation on how to do that.